# Move Existing SPListItem to an Existing SPFolder?

Tags: splistitem

Is there a way to programmatically move an existing list item (`SPListItem`) to a folder or do I need to make a new item that is a duplicate of the list item in the folder in question and then delete the old one?

Answer (score 2):

It is not explicitly a file but you can still use it as one. Here's an example I've used before:

```
SPListItem item;
SPList list;
SPWeb web;
string DestinationFolderPath;
SPFile file = web.GetFile(item.Url);
string destinationUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd(new Char[] { '/' }) + "/" + DestinationFolderPath + "/" + item.ID.ToString() + "_.000";
file.MoveTo(destinationUrl);
```

You could make a new item that is a duplicate but you'll run into issues if you have lookups to that item. Since the new item will have a new ID, the lookup will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

If its a file you can use the [SPFile.MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.moveto.aspx) command.

Comment: `SPListItem` Not a file.